# MIPS to C Translation

Tags: c, assembly, mips, reverse-engineering, translate

I need to translate some MIPS assembly instructions to C code. I think I got it, but it seems counter-intuitive. Any help? We have variables f, g, h, i, j stored in registers $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3 and $s4 respectively. The base of arrays A and B are stored in $s6 and $s7 respectively. 4 byte words. Comments in the code are my own.

```
addi $t0, $s6, 4   # $t0 = A[1]
add $t1, $s6, $0   # $t1 = A[0]
sw $t1, 0($t0)     # $t0 = A[0]
lw $t0, 0($t0)     # $t0 = A[0]
add $s0, $t1, $t0  # f = A[0] + A[0]
```

I just feel like I'm wrong. Why make $t0 A[1] first if we never use it?

Comment: [How to understand this basic Assembly Code that seems to be adding two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807155) has correct analysis of the same weird code, with correct comments like `&A[0]`, not `A[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sw $t1, 0($t0)     # $t0 = A[0]
```

You've got this back-to-front. It is a *store*, so it *is* used:

```
sw $t1, 0($t0)     # A[1] = $t1
```

Comment: I don't think so. My revision changes the meaning of the fourth line. What do you get when taking that into account?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have got in completely wrong.

`addi $t0, $s6, 4   # $t0 = A[1]`

After the addi, register `$t0` became the memory address of A[1], which would be `&A[1]`, not `A[1]`. To get value of A[1], you need to use `lw` after you done the `addi`

`lw $t0, 0($t0) # $t0 =A[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Just a little addition to the previous answers:
The store word means that you cannot access $t1 anymore because it is copied to memory. At least you should not use the $t1 from the store word instruction. You should use the one before (`add $t1, $s6, $0`). This means that the answer is `f ( which is in $s0) = &A[0] (base address in register $t1) + A[1] (value of the array with word index 1, which is in register $t0)`

Answer (score 1):

Mnush's answer is incorrect.

The last line is adding $t1 and $t0.

$t1 = A[0] and

$t0 = A[1].

With proper comments:

```
addi $t0, $s6, 4   # $t0 = &A[1]
add $t1, $s6, $0   # $t1 = &A[0]
sw $t1, 0($t0)     # A[0] = A[1]
lw $t0, 0($t0)     # $t0 = A[0]
add $s0, $t1, $t0  # f = A[0] + A[1]
```

The C Code:

```
A[1] = A[0];
f = A[0] + A[1];
```

Comment: It's adding addresses.  `f = &A[0] + &A[1]`.  This makes no sense, and in C would require casts to `(uintptr_t)`, but is what the asm actually does.

Comment: So is this the correct answer @PeterCordes?

`A[1] = A[0];
f = (unintptr_t)(&A[0] + &A[1]);`

Comment: No, you can't `+` between two pointers in C.  You have to cast at least one of the operands to `+`, not the result.  Also no, `A[1] = A[0];` isn't correct.  There's no load before the store, just address calculations / copies.

Comment: My answer on [How to understand this basic Assembly Code that seems to be adding two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807155) has accurate comments and C equivalents that will actually compile.  It's the same asm, but with correct comments it even in the question, so not exactly a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are using A[1] twice as shown:

- Register $t0 carries the address of the array from the first instruction

  ```
  sw $t1, 0($t0)    #  A[1] = $t1  =>  A[1] = &A[0]
  ```
- Load the value of the address ($t0 + 0) into register $t0

  ```
  lw $t0, 0($t0)   # $t0 = A[1]
  ```
- Essentialy =>

  ```
  $t0 = &A[0]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
    addi $t0, $s6, 4   # $t0 = &A[1]
    add $t1, $s6, $0   # $t1 = &A[0]
    sw $t1, 0($t0)     # A[1] = &A[0]
    lw $t0, 0($t0)     # $t0 = A[1]
    add $s0, $t1, $t0  # f = &A[0] + A[1]
```

C code:
f = &A[0] + A[1]

Comment: Yes, and `A[1]` holds a copy of `&A[0]`.  See [How to understand this basic Assembly Code that seems to be adding two pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63891264)

Answer (score -1):

Guess this is correct.

```
A[1] = A[0] 
f= A[1] + A[1]
```